# Turn Off Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

Using VS 2012, Entity Framework 5 and SQL Server Express 2012.

I have a SQL Server database to service an application using `Web API`; as it is mainly for use on mobile devices, I want to minimize data transfer so I would like to disable Navigation Properties. I've set `ProxyCreationEnabled` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` to false which means that the related data does not get serialized which helps a lot but they are still appearing as empty arrays in the data returned in calls to the `Web API`which means I will have to handle them some way in the `AJAX` calls.

Is there some way to turn them off completely?

Comment: Use DTO's. Don't make it a data layer responsibility to shape and optimize transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought Gert's answer was a bit terse so I ignored it originally. Actually, he is 100% right. I now realise that if you want any fine control over the data you are bringing across then DTO's (Data Transfer Objects) are the way to go.

I thought at first that there would be a lot of repetitive work in creating the DTO's but then I discovered [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) :)